# Jquery doesnt work on one of pages in app backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, debugging, backbone.js

Im trying to do my first debug ever. The scenario is that there is a notification dropdown in the header, the dropdown opens but does not close on only one on the pages and works fine everywhere else in the app.The problem is that on one of the pages, the dropdown opens but doesn't close, my guess is the jquery to close down the button does not work. And I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined.
```

When I put a breakpoint and call stacktrace above the line which has the error, for both working and not working pages, I compare the trace. I see, that if you take notice on the Call Stack on the right for the first image  (which is the one that works), the last Call Stack is jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle and the one not working has just elemData.handle.

Not working page: 
[image]

Working page:
[image]

relevant functions from the Call Stack:

class: notification_dropdown_view.js

```
app.views.NotificationDropdown = app.views.Base.extend({
events: {
"click #notifications-link": "toggleDropdown"
},

initialize: function(){
$(document.body).click($.proxy(this.hideDropdown, this));

this.notifications = [];
this.perPage = 5;
this.hasMoreNotifs = true;
this.badge = this.$el;
this.dropdown = $("#notification-dropdown");
this.dropdownNotifications = this.dropdown.find(".notifications");
this.ajaxLoader = this.dropdown.find(".ajax_loader");
this.perfectScrollbarInitialized = false;
},
....
etc etc
....

hideDropdown: function(evt){
var inDropdown = $(evt.target).parents().is($(".dropdown-menu", this.dropdown));
var inHovercard = $.contains(app.hovercard.el, evt.target);
if(!inDropdown && !inHovercard && this.dropdownShowing()){
  this.dropdown.removeClass("dropdown-open");
  this.destroyScrollbar();
}
}

toggleDropdown: function(evt){
evt.stopPropagation();
if (!$("#notifications-link .entypo-bell:visible").length) { return true; }
evt.preventDefault();
if(this.dropdownShowing()){ this.hideDropdown(evt); }
else{ this.showDropdown(); }
},
```

class: app.js:

```
setupGlobalViews: function() {
app.hovercard = new app.views.Hovercard();
$('.aspect_membership_dropdown').each(function(){
  new app.views.AspectMembership({el: this});
});
app.sidebar = new app.views.Sidebar();
},
```

Comment: So it is saying that `app.hovercard` is `undefined`, why would you expect it to be otherwise and what does this have to do with Backbone?

Comment: I thought 'el' has only to do with backbone. But now I know not necessarily. app.hovercard is defined in app.js. I've updated my post. Check.

Comment: Yes, a view's `el` is from Backbone but that's not the problem, the problem appears to be `app.hovercard`. Why do you think `app.hovercard` should be defined? Have you checked that `setupGlobalViews` is being run when you think it is? Is something else overwriting your `app` global somewhere?

Comment: oh my bad, It most certainly is the problem. `app.hovercard` is defined  in app.js because `new app.views.Hovercard()` makes the hovercard appear. The dropdown is now closing when I initialize using any of the following:  `this.app.hovercard;`, `this.app.hovercard:true;`, `this.app.hovercard:false;` inside notification_dropdown_view.js

Answer (score 0):

The two things that I always go to when dealing with dynamic states of elements that depend strictly on user interaction is the JavaScript `setInterval()` method or the jQuery `on.('propertychange click input');`